# How to loop an exploded list of strings?

Tags: php

I have a list of country names in an `input` field like:

> Spain Italy France Germany

So first of i make all the strings lowercase in order not to have a mismatch with the country name in the geoJson data. Then I compare the strings with the propriety name in the geoJson, and if it matches, i push it in the array.

```
$json = file_get_contents("../world_ita.json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$states = array();
$item = null;
$stateList = strtolower( usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-3'));
$stateList = htmlspecialchars_decode ( $stateList);
$stateList = preg_replace("/\w[\w']*/e", "ucwords('\\0')", $stateList);
$stateList = explode(' ',$stateList);
foreach($data["features"] as $feature) {
  $id = $feature["id"];
  $name = $feature["properties"]["name"];
  $feature["properties"]["density"] = 0;
  foreach($stateList as $state) {
    if ($name == $state) {
      if (!in_array($name, $states)) {
        $item = $feature;
        array_push($states, $name);
      }
    } else { ?> 
      statesData.features.forEach(function(state) {
        if ("<?php echo $id;?>" == state.id) {
          state.properties.density += 10;
        }
      });
<?php }
  }
}
if (!is_null($item)) : ?>
      statesData.features.push(<?php echo json_encode($item); ?>);
  <?php endif; ?>
```

The above is not working and it breaks it. I thought to first explode the strings and then loop them and run the other bits of the code, I am not sure where I am doing something wrong there.

**UPDATE**

What the above code does is to repeat the following for each single object in the geoJson

```
statesData.features.forEach(function(state) {
```

and it is not printing the coordinates as it should as I run the following by the end of it:

```
    if (!is_null($item)) : ?>
      statesData.features.push(<?php echo json_encode($item); ?>);
  <?php endif;
```

It is only printing one single country coordinates but the name are the same as per the geoJson, so it should print all matching ones.

> **UPDATE 2**

The code I am trying out is exactly this (different from the previous as per the new update):

```
      var statesData = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": []
      };

    <?php
        $json = file_get_contents("http://www.jikupin.com/world_ita.json");
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        $states = array();
        $classesForCountries = [];   
        $item = null;
        $stateList = strtolower( usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-3'));
        $stateList = htmlspecialchars_decode ( $stateList);
        $stateList = preg_replace("/\w[\w']*/e", "ucwords('\\0')", $stateList);
        $stateList = explode(' ',$stateList);
        foreach($data["features"] as $feature) {
          $name = $feature["properties"]["name"];
          foreach($stateList as $state) {
            if ($name == $state) {
              if (!in_array($name, $states)) {
                  $item = $feature;
                  array_push($states, $name);
              } 
            }
          }
        }
        if (!is_null($item)) : ?>
          statesData.features.push(<?php echo json_encode($item); ?>);
          <?php 
        endif; 
    ?>
```

The above is not printing any coordinates, If I remove the `explode` and the loop I do for it, meaning if i run it for one single country, it works. When I run the explode and the loop for for that, and I try `var_dumb($states)`, i get

```
value (0)
```

Comment: what does "breaks it" mean?>

Comment: `$stateList` is not defined. perhaps you meant `$state`

Comment: @rtfm sorry you are right, haven't explained well. Updated the question now, and also fixed the variable name but was a copy paste mistake, the result is the same

Comment: Please edit to show your actual code.  This makes no sense mixed into PHP code instead of HTML: if ("<?php echo $id;?>" == state.id) {

Comment: @DaveS I have updated, see if that gives you an idea now

Comment: Debugging suggestions: add some echo statements to see the value of $state and other variables for each loop.  Also, since  $item  is a single variable not an array you will only ever get one state here: `<?php echo json_encode($item); ?>`

Comment: @DaveS I am indeed only having one single state, so now the questions are 2 based on what you said: 1. How can I output all the states? 2. I see that the problem is with the explode, that foreach is giving me lots of repeating countries, i had to add some white space too, as "United Kingdom" has a white space in it so             `$stateList = explode('&nbsp;', $stateList); ` but then if i have 2 countries there wont' be white space as per "United KingdomSpain" and that obviously breaks it

Comment: @DaveS if i do  `echo $state; ` just after the           `foreach($stateList as $state) {` i get lots of them, even tho i should have only 4.

Comment: You have sample input `Spain Italy France Germany`. What is the expected output?